# IDE: autocomplete at django ORM double underscore

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, ide

Is there an IDE which knows the django ORM and can can tell me the matching completions after the double underscore?

Example:

```
Foo.objects.filter(due_date__ ???
```

The IDE should tell me that `gte` is a possible completion.

Example2:

```
Permission.objects.filter(content_type__???
```

here the IDE should tell me that `app_label` is a possible completion.

Comment: You can try [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

Comment: @salmanwahed does it support this feature?

Comment: I am using this ide(community edition) and it feels very good. About the particular instance of yours, i did not try it so i am not sure, but so far my using experience tells me that it'll be pretty good for `django` development. you can give it a try.

Comment: At least in 3.4.1 it doesn't support this particular feature

Answer (score 2):

Not really an IDE, but Sublime Text could do this. I haven't used Django in 2 years, and Sublime Text has changed a lot as well in that time, but give it a try.

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and some info on
[Django configuration for Sublime](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/03/install-and-configure-sublime-text-3.html)

ps. see also this [SO-topic: Which Django IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175044/django-development-ide?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm can do it. You can try professional edition for 30 days.

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

It supported in PyCharm5: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#DjangoORM

Comment: I just tried it, but it did not work. But maybe I am doing something wrong. I opened pyCharm for the first time.

Comment: User esauro thinks that it is not possible with 3.4.1 and I tried it, and it did not work. Maybe in the future?

Comment: This feature request is already reported:  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-3999